How do 2 query plans on the same table have large row estimation differences
Problem
Query 1 estimates 5963187197 rows for table, but Query 2 estimates 2484661332 rows for table. Actual value is 5956933728
Default max_parallel_workers_per_gather is 2, I suspect the row estimates are per worker.



max_parallel_workers_per_gather
rows
multiplied_total




1
3507757175
3507757175


2
2484661332
4969322664


4
1490796799
5963187196


6
993864533
5963187198


8
745398400
5963187200



Actual machine is EC2 db.r5.2xlarge 4 core  8 vcpu
Questions

Are the stats really per worker?  Why does the multiplied_total diverge more from real counts with decreasing max_parallel_workers_per_gather?
Can we read per worker stats then assume all workers will
behave in similar ways, finishing at similar times?

Query 1
explain select * from table
Output
Seq Scan on table (cost=10000000000.00..10650862079.97 rows=5963187197 width=739)
Query 2
explain
select key, count(*)
from table
group by key

Output
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1000.61..3555907849.26 rows=487 width=15)
  Group Key: key
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.61..3555907839.52 rows=974 width=15)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=0.58..3555906727.07 rows=487 width=15)
              Group Key: key
              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using key_idx on table (cost=0.58..3543483415.54 rows=2484661332 width=7)

